# How long would fruit in a water bottle last?

Tags: food-safety, fruit, water

I have a plastic, refillable water bottle that I fill with water from our purifying pitcher. I have recently begun adding sliced fresh fruits, like strawberries and kiwis, inside the bottle to give the water a natural, fruity flavor.

How long would these fruits last in a water bottle? How often should I replace them with new fruit.

I recall a few years ago my mother made cucumber-flavored water through the same concept, only she put the sliced cucumbers directly in the pitcher and put it in the fridge, so it was constantly refrigerated. The cucumbers seemed to last a while, but my water bottle would not be refrigerated often as I am constantly sipping from it throughout the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technical answer based on food safety agency recommendations is about 4 hours, but fruit is not exceptionally perishable.   If you are not in any high risk group, you might choose to go a day.

Comment: You could stretch this by using an insulated bottle with ice water; then you'll have at least 4 hours from when the ice disappears.